# Azure Web Job with Quartz failing

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, quartz.net

I've published a console app as a continuously running web job, using Quartz to manage the scheduling.

Quartz works fine when I run the file locally.

When I run the file as a web job, I can see that it runs on schedule, and does what it's supposed to.

However, when I look at the web job logs, I see errors like this:

```
[07/06/2017 09:48:59 > dd118a: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm seeing other, similar questions on here, but typically this involves people having assembly mismatch issues on their local machine.

How do I check to see if this error is critical, and how do I fix it?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I do a test with the following sample code using Quartz.NET library (v2.5.0), it works fine both on local and deployed as WebJobs.

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuartzTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter { Level = Common.Logging.LogLevel.Info };

                // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
                IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

                // and start it off
                scheduler.Start();

                // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();

                // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

                // some sleep to show what's happening
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

                // and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
                scheduler.Shutdown();
            }
            catch (SchedulerException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se);
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application");
            //Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public class HelloJob : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Greetings from HelloJob!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Common.Logging" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.Core" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Quartz" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

WebJobs logs

[image]

> Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please use [the Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to access to your site’s folder and make sure Quartz and its dependencies files are there (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous{jobname}). And you can try to delete and redeploy your job to your Azure web app.

[image]

Besides, [Azure WebJob itself can be triggered on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledcronacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression), if possible, you can use it.